# MVVM-Light EventToCommand UserControl_SizeChanged

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I used in wired view-code behind to write something like this

```
private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewSize.Width < _originalWidth ||
    .....
}
```

How I can handle events in Silverlight UserControl itself using EvnentToCommand in MVVMLight.

I tried to add this code in XAML but have no luck.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand 
            Command="{Binding onSizeChangedRelayCommand, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=this}" **// Edit: ElementName=this has been removed**
            PassEventArgsToCommand="True">
        </cmd:EventToCommand>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Why use `ElementName=this` your viewmodel with `onSizeChangedRelayCommand` is not the `DataContext` ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm sorry ElementName=this is not there. I'm a beginner to MVVM. I use it with all Elements. My question was how to use it with the Shell events such as SizeChanged. I keep SizeChanged in the code-behind of the shell. I wish I could use EventToCommand with the shell, which his not firing with me.